# Determine the integral $\int_{C} xy^2 \ dx + x^2y \ dy$ when $C$ denotes the circle $x^2+y^2=a^2, a>0.$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Determine the integral $$\int_{C} xy^2 \ dx + x^2y \ dy$$ when $C$ denotes the circle $x^2+y^2=a^2, a>0.$

I have that $F(x,y) = (xy^2, x^2y)$ which is a conservative vector field and the circle is a closed loop so one would assume that the integral would be $0$?

I got that $$\iint_D 2xy-2xy \ dA = \iint_D 0 \ dA = 0$$ I'm not sure if my reasoning here is correct?

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, by [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Theorem).

Being "conservative" also means that the line integral is path independent.